# Pagination on Propel ORM

Tags: pagination, propel

i paginated the propel results, its all working fine, but i cant get this thing working. I will really appreciate any help or workaround this issue:

```
<?if ($posts->getPage()==???) { ?>
<a href='?p=<?echo end($linkPrevNext);?>'  class="pagNext">next</a>
<?}?>
```

the function getPage() returns to me the active page, but what should i put on the ??? to hide the last next link on propel, some function like $posts->getLastPage() that actually works. I just cant get any info about this on the Propel documentation.

to hide the first 'previous' link, i used this:

```
<?if ($posts->getPage()>1) { ?>
<a href='?p=<?echo $linkPrevNext[0];?>'  class="pagPrev">prev</a>
<?}?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getLastPage()` will return the page number of the last page. `atLastPage()` is a convenience function that will already do the comparison for you, and also exists as `atFirstPage()`. See the API docs for Propel [1.3](http://api.propelorm.org/1.3.0/runtime/propel-util/PropelPager.html), [1.4](http://api.propelorm.org/1.4.0/runtime/propel-util/PropelPager.html), [1.5](http://api.propelorm.org/1.5.0/runtime/propel-runtime-util/PropelPager.html) or [1.6](http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.0/runtime/propel-runtime-util/PropelPager.html).

You code could look like this:

```
<?php if (!$posts->atLastPage()) { ?>
<a href='?p=<?php echo $posts->getLastPage(); ?>'  class="pagNext">next</a>
<?php } ?>
```

I assumed `$linkPrevNext` contains just the page numbers, like it came from `$posts->getNextLinks()`. If not, you should not use `getLastPage()` in the link of course.